# MongoDB: removeShard when dbsToMove is an empty array

Tags: mongodb, migration, sharding

### Background:

- Two empty shards with no explicit sharding scheme -  `shard0000` and `shard0001`.
- `mongorestore` a single database, all of which defaults to shard0000
- Add a shard key to one collection and let the balancer move 1171 chunks to shard0001, leaving 1171 on shard0000. (So far, so good.)
- Manually move 2 chunks from shard0000 to shard0001, one of which happens to contain the highest values of the shard key. **UPDATE:** I had suspected this is where things got tricky, but I repeated the entire procedure described here without this manual move, and got the exact same results.

  - The result, according to `sh.status({"verbose":true})` is both chunks simply having their assigned shard names changed from "shard0000" to "shard0001", including the row at the end of the output with `{ "key_field" : "highest_value" } -->> { "key_field" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on shard0001 Timestamp(1173, 0)`.
  - Totals are shard0000=1169 and shard0001=1173, as expected.
  - The only database listed has shard0000 as its primary.

### Next steps:

- Attempt to move all of the data back to shard0000 using `db.runCommand({removeShard:"shard0001"})`

The initial return value, as well as all subsequent reruns of the above command, documented to give the status of the `removeShard` operation, is

```
{
        "msg" : "draining ongoing",
        "state" : "ongoing",
        "remaining" : {
                "chunks" : NumberLong(1173),
                "dbs" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "note" : "you need to drop or movePrimary these databases",
        "dbsToMove" : [ ],  <-- THE PROBLEM
        "ok" : 1
}
```

- Considering that there is only one database, attempt to `movePrimary` it just in case. As expected, this returns `{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "it is already the primary" }`
- `sh.status()` shows shard0001 as "draining" : true.
- The "remaining" count does not change.
- Moving back the two manually moved chunks to shard0000 does not affect the results.
- There are no outstanding locks. `db.locks.find({"state":2})` returns nothing.
- The mongos log shows these two relevant operations, then nothing. (The shards' logs have no trace of this, with default verbosity.)

  - `SHARDING [conn5] going to start draining shard: shard0001`
  - `SHARDING [conn5] about to log metadata event into changelog: { _id: ..., server: ..., clientAddr: ..., time: ..., what: "removeShard.start", ns: "", details: { shard: "shard0001" } }`
- No chunks are jumbo. `db.chunks.find({shard: "shard0001","jumbo":true})` returns nothing.
- `db.runCommand({flushRouterConfig:1})` does not affect any of the above.

### Question:

Is there really something I need to movePrimary here, despite the empty array for `dbsToMove`? If so, what is it and where did it come from? Have I made some more basic error in moving all of the data back to one shard?

### Disclaimers:

- There are several questions on SO about troubles with removeShard ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714386/use-removeshard-to-remove-a-shard-but-its-not-work-well)), most of which do not address specifically the case of `dbsToMove: [ ]`.
- The one that does ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954914/mongodb-use-removeshard-to-remove-shard-but-still-on-draing-at-all)) has no answers, and I am hoping that by providing more details I can solicit one.
- [The documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/sharding/) says "nor can you unshard a collection", which is essentially what I'm trying to do, but I wouldn't necessarily conclude from that that I can't drain a shard.
- I found [this bug ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17397), but it doesn't seem directly related to this problem.

**MongoDB 3.2.9**